# Problem defining a function that takes a binary input to its decimal form

Tags: function-construction, number-bases

I am trying to define a function which takes a binary number and gives the decimal form. I tried the following

`binarytodecimal[b_] := NumberForm[2^^b, 20]`

But the variable `b` is not recognised by Mathematica, I think because of the `^^`. I have tried reading the documentation to see if there is another way to input a binary number but I haven't found anything.

As an example, take 0.0100101010101010101010. Then `NumberForm[2^^0.0100101010101010101010, 20]` computes but trying to turn this into a function does not work.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: In what format are you providing the binary number? As an ordinary "decimal" number (``b = 1011001``) or as a string (``b = "1011001"``) or as a list of digits (``b = {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}``).

Comment: `FromDigits[b, 2]` ? e.g `FromDigits[{1, 1, 0, 1}, 2]` gives 13

Comment: @Domen Sorry about that, I've updated the question with an example. I am using ordinary numbers and usually these are not integers.

Comment: @flinty The numbers I am working with are not integers, they are between 0 and 1 so I don't think your solution works in this case. I've added an example to the question.

Comment: `FromDigits[RealDigits[0.0100101010101010101010, 10], 2]` gives 611669/2097152 and using `N` gives 0.291667

Comment: @flinty that seems to work, thanks!

Comment: @math, I think this double caret is some very low-level syntactic "thing", which cannot be evaluated together with other symbols, but only with numerical symbols (i.e. numerals, decimal point and letters). For example: ``b = 1101; 2^^b`` does not work.

Comment: Following my comment, in the [open-source parser](https://github.com/WolframResearch/codeparser/blob/32a181f34d3197a5777ea24d01e86b06271f988d/cpp/src/lib/Tokenizer.cpp) for Wolfram Language (line 1051), you can see that ``base^^digits`` gets tokenized as a single token, and therefore this double caret is not a proper "symbol" or "operator".

Comment: @math, very good question. indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code

```
binarytodecimal[b_String] := NumberForm[ToExpression["2^^"<>b], 20];
```

does what you want. For example

```
binarytodecimal["0.0100101010101010101010"]
```

evaluates to `0.2916665077209473`